# DynamoDB and get item sorted

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've started using DynamoDB about 2 weeks ago, and now I've the necessity to get item based on a Sort Column... I've created my table as Token (PK) , CreateTimestamp (sort) but I've find no way of sorting on the CreateTimestamp column. I need this since I need to read the highest attribute that's defined on the last inserted row. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Try to configure the CreateTimestamp field as a local secondary index, then query against it.

Comment: yes but how do I query it if I've no key to filter on? can I perform queries, without having to specify the key?

Comment: If `CreateTimestamp` is your sort key, query results will automatically sorted by that field.  Are you trying to sort by `CreateTimestamp` across *all* partitions?

Comment: It continues to give me a value that's in the middle...tomorrow I ll let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use composite keys, let call them Partition Key (PK) and Sort Key (SK).

To get the all the items in order, first you need to put them in the same partition (same PK value), then create a SK with the condition you wanna sort. For example:

If you wanna sort by date, oldest to newest, you can leverage [KSUID](https://github.com/segmentio/ksuid)

```
{
  "PK": {
    "S": "PK"
  },
  "SK": {
    "S": "272XuKFxQEa1VTj5dHEaKXWXBdc"
  }
}
```

`272XuKFxQEa1VTj5dHEaKXWXBdc` is create from `2022-03-29 09:02:55.460868`

The default query will automatically get the oldest first, in case you wanna get the newest, you can set the param `ScanIndexForward` to `false` [detail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html).

Otherwise, if you wanna sort as the number increment (0,1,2,3,etc) you need to use the padded number as below:

```
{
  "PK": {
    "S": "PK"
  },
  "SK": {
    "S": "0000000"
  }
},
{
  "PK": {
    "S": "PK"
  },
  "SK": {
    "S": "0000001"
  }
}
```

The query can be same as above.

Comment: excuse me but If I want to have all the items I can't use the scan (since it doesn't guarantee the order) but the query, using query I've to specify a  Key Condition but I need to get all, not based on my PK

Comment: I just showed you the design entity structure to sort when query something

Comment: @advapi did you passed PK. I am facing same issue. I need to get all data. How can we do it without using PK. I have checked all the documentation didn't get a proper answer. i need to do pagination also. How did you done it ?

Comment: you've to do a scan if no passing the PK